# what is the dict class used for

Tags: python

Can someone explain what the `dict` class is used for? This snippet is from *Dive Into Python*

```
class FileInfo(dict):                  
    "store file metadata"
    def __init__(self, filename=None): 
        self["name"] = filename
```

I understand the assignment of key=value pairs with `self['name'] = filename` but what does inheriting the `dict` class have to do with this? Please help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for creating your own customized Dictionary type.

You can override `__init__`, `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods for your own special purposes to extend dictionary's usage.

Read the next section in the Dive into Python text: we use such inheritance to be able to work with file information just the way we do using a normal dictionary.

```
# From the example on the next section
>>> f = fileinfo.FileInfo("/music/_singles/kairo.mp3")
>>> f["name"]
'/music/_singles/kairo.mp3'
```

The `fileinfo` class is designed in a way that it receives a file name in its constructor, then lets the user get file information just the way you get the values from an ordinary dictionary.

Another usage of such a class is to create dictionaries which control their data. For example you want a dictionary who does a special thing when things are assigned to, or read from its 'sensor' key. You could define your special `__setitem__` function which is sensitive with the key name:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    self.data[key] = item
    if key == "sensor":
        print("Sensor activated!")
```

Or for example you want to return a special value each time user reads the 'temperature' key. For this you subclass a `__getitem__` function:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key == "temperature":
        return CurrentWeatherTemperature()
    else:
        return self.data[key]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not familiar with inheritance concept of object-oriented programming have a look at least at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29) wiki article (though, that's only for introduction and may be not for the best one).

In python we use this syntax to define class `A` as subclass of class `B`:

```
class A(B):
  pass # empty class
```

In your example, as `FileInfo` class is inherited from standard [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) type you can use instances of that class as dictionaries (as they have all methods that regular `dict` object has). Besides other things that allows you assign values by key like that (`dict` provides method for handing this operation):

```
self['name'] = filename
```

Is that the explanation you want or you don't understand something else?

Comment: @KL-7--would you mind providing a different example of a subclass inherited from `dict`? how does one use this in practice?

Comment: I don't think people often create subclasses of `dict` or other built-in types, but [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html) is an implementation of ordered dictionary. As you can see in the [source](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/odict.py) `OrderedDict` class is a subclass of `dict` type.

Answer (score 1):

When an Class in Python inherits from another Class, it means that any of the methods defined on the inherited Class are, by nature, defined on the newly created Class.

So when `FileInfo` inherits `dict` it means all of the functionality of the `dict` class is now available to `FileInfo`, in addition to anything that `FileInfo` may declare, or more importantly, override by re-defining the method or parameter.

Since the `dict` Object in Python allows for key/value name pairs, this enables `FileInfo` to have access to that same mechanism.

Comment: @tkone--is inheriting the `dict` object mandatory for key value pairs? Doesnt every python object have this ability?

Comment: No, that's JavaScript :).  Python objects have attributes which can be accessed via the 'dot' notation (`test.parameter`).  `dict` is an associative array where you access the values by using the associated key.  Try instantiating an object in Python and accessing it as if it were an associative array `test['parameter']`.  You'll get `TypeError: 'Test' object is not subscriptable.`  Now make a dict and try to access it via the 'dot' notation. You'll `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute N`